# Codeigniter Active Record, Where in

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I have join table with where in 
I am wondering if there is a way i can say something like this :

```
where kd_x in (select kd_x from master_code where a='11921212')
```

I'm trying to do this with active record like this but is doesn't give me any data

```
$this->db->where_in('kd_x',array('select kd_x from MT_master where a="11921212"'));
```

Help me Please, Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->where()` you can use 2nd and 3rd argument, so that any string you can pass

```
$this->db->where('`kd_x`  IN (select `kd_x` from `MT_master` where a="11921212")', NULL, FALSE);
```

OR

```
//Create where clause
$this->db->select('kd_x')
         ->where('a','11921212')
         ->from('MT_master');
$where_clause = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

//Create main query
$this->db->select('*');
     ->from('your_table');
     ->where("`kd_x` IN ($where_clause)", NULL, FALSE);
```